# Tokenizing a String to an Array from Standard Input

Tags: arrays, c, string, tokenize

I am currently writing a program in C, but I am encountering an error.

***Overview***
The program I am writing uses standard input to read in two sets of data simultaneously: a two-dimensional array and a string of numbers (the size is unknown at the time of input). It then determines if the array contains the numbers found within the string.

For example, an input would be:

```
12 29 39 57 61
15 30 45 60 75
07 23 00 46 68
02 18 37 51 70
10 27 32 55 71

12 20 15 40 45 32 71 07 56 51 36 55 19 10 43 23 70 11 27 60 67 03 72 33 56 09 02
```

***Problem***
Right now, I am focusing on tokenizing the input string, so that I can easily compare its elements to the elements of the 2D array. So, I wrote the following code to test my approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    // declare variables
    char inputNumsString[225];  // undelimited input
    char numbersCalled[75];     // delimited numbers

    // retrieve numbers from input
    fgets(inputNumsString, 225, stdin);

    // 
    char delim[] = " ";
    int stringSize = strlen(inputNumsString);
    char *ptr = strtok(inputNumsString, delim);
    int x = 0;
    
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        int temp = atoi(ptr);
        numbersCalled[x] = temp;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        x = x + 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", numbersCalled[i]);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
    
    
}
```

When I execute the program, the numbers are outputted correctly. However, since the array has been initialized to a length of 75, it also appends several other integer values that I both dont need and can't have as it will interfere when comparing the contents to an array.

```
12, 20, 15, 40, 45, 32, 71, 7, 56, 51, 36, 55, 19, 10, 43, 23, 70, 11, 27, 60, 67, 3, 72, 33, 56, 9, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -80, 9, -127, -64, -2, 127, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -88, 9, -127, -64, -2, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49,
```

I guess my question is whether or not there is a way I can remove the extraneous values. As the different test cases will have different sizes, I cannot alter the size of the array at initialization for this specific string. And since array size's cannot be changed after initialization, I don't see another option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should get the correct converted number count if you change `for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++).

Comment: That would only change the output, but does not change the contents of the array. The extraneous values would still be stored in the memory, which will affect any expressions written to compare with the 2D array

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, even if it is inefficient. After the while loop, I created a new array of size x, and used a for loop to iterate through each of the values and store them in the new array.

```
while (ptr != NULL) {
        int temp = atoi(ptr);
        numbersCalled[x] = temp;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        x = x + 1;
    }
    
    char finalString[x];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        finalString[i] = numbersCalled[i];
    }
```